# How to pass data from one screen to another in wix react native navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

I am new to this React native and javascript as a whole. I am trying to pass data from one screen to another using wix react native navigation.
Here is my code
On screen one

```
 _gotoAnotherScreen = (screen,data) => {
        this.props.navigator.push({
            screen: screen,
            title: data.title,
            passProps: {
                data: data
            }
        });
    };
```

And my data is an array

And on the 2nd screen i am trying to catch the value like this

```
const { params } = this.props.navigator;
 console.log(params);
```

This is saying undefined

Can anyone please tell me how i can catch the data.

I tried to follow this thread , [Passing Data Using React-Native Navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45109872/passing-data-using-react-native-navigation)
But those ansers giving me error saying trying to get property of undefined.

Any help please . Thank you

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

After lot of looking here and there and some trial and error i found out.

it can used just like any other object.
like this `this.props.data`

Answer (score 1):

At First screen. Pass param like this.

```
 this.props.navigation.navigate({
            screen: "SecondScreen",
            params: { data: data }
 });
```

At second screen, You can catch param value like this.

```
componentDidMount() {
  const {data} = this.props.navigation.state.params;
}
```

Comment: this gives error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined` . How ever `this.props.data` give the passed data

Comment: Maybe there is no navigation prop in your screen. Btw, what you mentioned thread is using "react-navigation" not "wix-react-native-navigation".
My answer is only for "react-navigation" . I am sorry that I didn't well aware your question.

Comment: Thats ok,  and yes your answer is correct for react navigation. But for wix react native navigation that does not work. :)