# Update Data from one to. another screen

Tags: react-native

hey guys I'm using a text field that can show my global variable value
when I update global variable ex:- global.xx++
it can't refresh  when I click on it .how do I update data at once from many screen.. here's my ex

```
class A extend component
{
if(responseJson.responseCode == '200'){
                          ++global.cartitems ;
                          Obj.onPress();
                            Obj.componentDidMount();
                        Alert.alert('SHOPPING','Item added successfully.',[{text: 'OK',},],{ cancelable: false })

                        }

class b extend component
{
  <Text
             style={{color:'white',textAlign:'center',fontSize:10}}

             >{global.cartitems}</Text>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you meant is to pass a value from one screen to another.

You can either use [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage) to keep the data inside your memory, or pass the data through props [navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47858644/8645857)

AsyncStorage example:

Store Data:

```
_storeData = async () => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@MySuperStore:key', 'I like to save it.');
  } catch (error) {
    // Error saving data
  }
}
```

Fetch Data:

```
_retrieveData = async () => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('TASKS');
    if (value !== null) {
      // We have data!!
      console.log(value);
    }
   } catch (error) {
     // Error retrieving data
   }
}
```

Passing data through props navigation:

First class:

```
<Button onPress = {
  () => navigate("ScreenName", {name:'Jane'})
} />
```

Second class:

```
const {params} = this.props.navigation.state
```

Comment: it helpful but not in my case

Comment: Hmm.. can you elaborate more?

Comment: I have a cart counts which is in another file and I'm updating cart count on products screen so that every time I click on + icon cart count can be +1

Comment: Then using props navigation and asyncstorage is out of the question. I suggest storing the value inside the database tied to the user, as user might log out and log in back or close and open the app.

Comment: can u be more specific

Comment: As props navigation is only passing one screen to another, then it's not applicable, same goes for asyncstorage, it is just a temporary storage in your memory. Since I assume you're creating an app like amazon for example, you need to call your backend to store that number to your database. Then fetch that number in every screen.