# How to transfer data between screens in Drawer navigation in React-Native

Tags: react-native, navigation, navigation-drawer

I want to take state value of one screen to another screen. How to do it? Both screens are under drawer navigation.

Answer (score 0):

**To pass the value between different activities**

**Approach 1**: 
Pass params to a route by putting them in an object as a second parameter to the navigation.navigate function from First Screen. Using :

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('RouteName', { /* params go here */ })
```

Read the params in your Second screen. Using:

```
this.props.navigation.getParam(paramName, defaultValue)
```

**Approach 2**:
By using redux. With it, you create a shared store of variables, so you can access them anywhere in the application. The following link demonstrates how to configure redux in your project. [https://blog.cloudboost.io/getting-started-with-react-native-and-redux-6cd4addeb29](http://The%20ideal%20way%20to%20do%20this%20is%20through%20redux.%20With%20it,%20you%20create%20a%20shared%20store%20of%20variables,%20so%20you%20can%20access%20them%20anywhere%20in%20the%20application.%20The%20following%20link%20demonstrates%20how%20to%20configure%20redux%20in%20your%20project.%20https://blog.cloudboost.io/getting-started-with-react-native-and-redux-6cd4addeb29)

Comment: There are many answers for the same question on StackOverflow for ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45109872/passing-data-using-react-native-navigation

Comment: Link can't be reached